# Ajax Call not returning Partial View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am making an `AJAX` call, and then returning `PartialView` from Controller to populate it in a `div`.

The following is my code :-

```
var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];

jq.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Main/getData',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {  
                    jq('#partialPlaceHolder').html(response);    
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Some Error Occured");
                }
            });

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult getData(FormCollection form)
        {
            ......

            return PartialView("_pageMain", retMod);
        }
```

As I debug the Code in Controller, there is no Error till the end, But still the AJAX throws the `alert("Some Error Occured")`.

The PartialView is not populated in div. How to solve this?

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify(formData)` or to see the content of the response in developer tools?

Comment: Is the partialview html or json?

Comment: PartialView  is .cshtml... I have used this in my other module it works there....Because i am posting here `file` so it is giving error..

Comment: Something similar, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/748842/Rendering-a-Partial-View-and-JSON-Data-Using-AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the return data type to json

```
dataType: 'json'
```

try changing this to

```
dataType: 'html'
```

See here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
Type: String
The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `.load()` [JQuery .load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/)?

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

And simple:

```
$('#partialPlaceHolder').load("@Url.Action('getData')", { form: formData })
```

Third parameter for `.load()` is callback function, so feels free with it.

BTW: I did not find using variable `file` in your code.